# Finding what I asked about getting a comment

Tags: support, comment, specific-question

I beg your pardon that I'm vague. I think I remember posting a question several years ago and that it was here on math. I think that the question was about probability and/or some paradox but I don't remember. I'm certain though that I got one comment that was something like

> All these years of learning mathematics and I never thought of this....

I want to find what I was writing about. I'm nearly certain that the comment was serious and that the question was received. It was not advanced mathematics. It was maybe a paradox or similar to a paradox.

There is the http://data.stackexchange.com/ but it might not work for such vagueness. It has happened before that I got help finding what I was looking for even though the information is vague.

Comment: You've made [12 posts about probability](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5602+probability) and [1 post about a paradox](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5602+paradox), so you could just check the comments on all of them.

Comment: @Rahul Of course. I found it in a minute http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440161/what-happens-when-a-probability-actually-occurs

Comment: Out of curiosity I took a look at the question and, oddly, I see no way in which the accepted answer would be addressing the concerns raised in the question (the other answer at least tries to...).

Comment: And if there are more posts, you can indeed try using SEDE with checking several possible words. This querey finds the comment when searching for the word [years](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/615875/comments-containing-given-keyword-on-my-posts?Word=years&userid=5602), but not when I tried "never" or "learning". (Of course, it is much easier to search for something now, since you already found it and I know the exact text of the comment. My points is that you remembered what comment roughly looked like and trying some of those words would work in this case.)